# How can I make sure my webapp would work on all Browsers?

Tags: web-applications

How can I make sure my webapp would work on all Browsers ? 
Instead of testing my site if my CSS and JScripts work fine on all browsers what are the steps or tool I should consider while starting my development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know about offline tool but if you are interested in online testing tool then you should try this: [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) and [best-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-ease-your-browser-compatibility-testing-efforts/](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-ease-your-browser-compatibility-testing-efforts/)

---

> The best to ensure your site works
>   well in all browser is testing it in
>   all browser manually.

---

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming there is such a tool or methodology.

The best methodology to ensure that your webapp will work on all browsers is to test your webapp on all browsers.

Ensuring that CSS and javascript work correctly on all browsers is hard work and required lots of experience and understanding of how the different browsers work.

---

For CSS, start with a good [reset CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

For javascript, use the most common version.

For both, avoid browser specific extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Browser Cam](http://www.browsercam.com/).  To verify the usability of your website I'd use something like [Click Tale](http://clicktale.com/).  Best of luck.